# How to move text to the Right in HTML?

Tags: html, css, image

I know that by adding `style="right: 100px;"` to an image, it can move an image slightly to the right. How can I do this with text, I want to move the text 100px to the right. I'd rather not use CSS but if I have to that's fine.

Comment: Adding ONLY `right: 100px;` won't move the image to right, you need to give some position to the image

Answer (score 8):

This is another approach for people (like me) not into the `position` CSS property:

```
#my-text {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

/* or an inline style */
style="float: right; margin-right: 100px;"
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a relative position:

```
#yourText {
    position: relative;
    left: -100px;
}
```

This will position it **relative** of where it used to be.

Answer (score 1):

You want to manage the style of your page content. So you have to use CSS.

Doorknob answers is perfectly good (and is probably the right one), but you could also set a negative margin (Note that its `position` attribute will remain `static`)

```
#yourText {
    margin-left: -100px;
}
```

or

```
style="margin-left: -100px;"
```